# How may I reduce the number of mouse clicks to look at the sources of the packages of one module? Currently I have five mouse clicks to do each time

Tags: java, intellij-idea, package

I do not know, in advance, the name of the *Java* source or the package I'm looking for.
With *Tree Appearance: Flatten Package*, in *Project View*, I'm starting here:

[image]

The first mouse click I'm doing leads me here:

[image]

The second one:

[image]

The third:

[image]

Fourth:

[image]

Fifth:

[image]

And this isn't convenient. Most of my modules have a single package, but I have twenty modules in my project, and developing with *IntelliJ* is: *click click click click click click click...*

I'm missing an option somewhere that (like in *Eclipse*, if I remember well) opens by default a folded *Java* module on its first package available.

Meaning that by clicking on the module name, in the first picture, I would immediately see what is shown on the last picture of my question.

Is it possible?

Of course, if then all the packages of my module are unfolded and clearly shown, it could be interesting. But if only the first package is opened, showing its sources, it would be already convenient.

Comment: You can also navigate the tree using arrow keys. Is that better?

Comment: @Sweeper it replaces five mouse clicks by ten key hits: at each step, one key left to open the level, one key down to go to the next level below. So I'm sorry, but it doesn't really help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the top of the navigator, there is a dropdown menu:

[image]

If you switch that to "Packages" (with two clicks), it shows you all the packages:

[image]

With just one more click on a package, you get something similar to your last picture, showing you the classes.

Also note that you can navigate this tree with arrow keys. Up and down to select a node, left to expand a node/select the child node, and right to collapse a node/select the parent node. So you *technically* don't need any "clicks".

Another option would be to find the parent folder of the packages using the shortcut for Navigate -> Files... (it's command-shift-O on macOS, not sure about Windows)

[image]

If your modules have a consistent directory structure, this could be useful since the folder you are looking for has a known name, like "main", "test", or "java".